# Jquery autosave when input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosave

In my CMS (Wordpress) system I'll use a colorpicker.

```
<tr valign="top">  
  <th scope="row"><?php esc_html_e('Omlijning', 'webthesign'); ?></th> 
  <td valign="middle">
    <input type="text" id="headerBorderColor1" style="background-color: #<?php echo get_option('we_header_border_color'); ?>" maxlength="6" size="8" value="<?php echo strtoupper(get_option('we_header_border_color')); ?>" name="update_headerBorderColor" />
  </td>
</tr>                          

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('input[name=update_headerBorderColor]').change(function () { 

     var statusVal = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({ type: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo $autosave_link; ?>",
              data: "update_headerBorderColor=" + statusVal,
              success: function({

                $('.success_update_headerBorderColor').fadeIn(200).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);} 

            })
    });
  });
</script
```

In the script code i'll use a autosave option. When I click on the input field, i'll will get a popup with the colorpicker. 
The problem is what function I need for autosave this script. 
When I use :

```
$('input[name=update_headerBorderColor]').change(function () {
```

The change function is not working with the colorpicker, because i'm out of the input. When I change the input manualy for example FFF, then the change function is working well.

Is there somebody to help me?

Thanks!

Comment: does the picker not have any events you could hook into?

Comment: The colorpicker plugin you are using should have an event surfaced for when a color is picked (through manual input or clicking in the popup). For example, if you were using [this colorpicker](http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/) you'd pass a `commitCallback` to the initial `colorpicker` function.

Comment: I'm using this: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/
Is there a callback function in it, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a callback on your color picker where you are setting the chosen color back into the textfield. Invoke this function as a part of the callback and it should solve the issue.

Comment: can you give me a example. Is that in the colorpicker function, or in the script that I post above?